# Java Socks5 Proxy Authentication

Tags: java, android

```
public void setProxy(){
 if(WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.PROXY_OVERRIDE)) {
            ProxyConfig proxyConfig = new ProxyConfig.Builder()
                . addProxyRule("123.123.123.123:8080")
                . addDirect().build();
            ProxyController.getInstance().setProxyOverride(proxyConfig, new Executor() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Runnable command) {
                        //do nothing
                    }
                }, new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.w(TAG, "WebView");
            
                    }
                });
}
}     

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
               @Override
                public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
                   
                    handler.proceed("user", "pass");
                }
           });
```

socks proxy connects without using password. But this code is not working for username - password authentication. It only works for HTTPS proxy. What should I do

Comment: did you find anything ?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. If you find a solution, then please tell me.